# Can't change button background image

Tags: ios, image, grid

I am using Xcode 6, and I am very new to iOS development.

I am trying to set a background image on an button. I have the button inside of a grid cell. Here is the code I have tried:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell

    if(indexPath.row + 1 == 1){
        [cell.gridButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];        
    }

    return cell;
}
```

I have tried some other methods but I am not having any luck. Could anyone please help me and possibly explain.

Comment: If you are new to iOS, you need to be using the latest tools. Update to Xcode 7 before you do anything else.

Comment: can you show your Cell for RowAtIndexpath method

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I updated my question.